# How to create dataframe from dictionary having list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dictionary:

```
adict = {'dic1': [{'a': True, 'b': False, 'c': True, 'd': True, 'z': False}],
         'dic2': [{'e': True, 'f': False, 'g': False}]}
```

How can I create dataframe in this format?

|  | True | False |
| --- | --- | --- |
| dic1 | a | b |
|  | c | z |
|  | d |  |
| dic2 | e | f |
|  |  | g |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
(pd.DataFrame({i:j[0] for i,j in adict.items()})
.stack()
.to_frame().rename_axis(['d',None])
.assign(cc = lambda x: x.groupby([pd.Grouper(level=1),0]).cumcount())
.reset_index(level=0)
.set_index([0,'cc'],append=True)['d']
.unstack(level=1)
.droplevel(1)
.sort_index(axis=1,ascending=False))
```

or

```
d2 = {True:[],False:[]}

for k,v in d.items():
    for k2,v2 in v[0].items():
        d2.get(v2).append((k,k2))

(v := pd.DataFrame(d2).stack()).to_frame('s').set_index(v.str[0],append=True)['s'].str[-1].unstack(level=1).reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
```

Output:

```
0    True False
dic1    a     b
dic1    c     z
dic1    d   NaN
dic2    e     f
dic2  NaN     g
```

Comment: Thankyou, this is useful but is there a way to stop repeating the dic1 and dic2 and just merge dic1 in one row keeping the values of True and False column in a separate rows? If that is possible, that will be a huge help. Basically, my actual dictionary is very big, dataframe won't be efficient if the variable dic1 and dic2 repeated